# How to authenticate user in LDAP/AD with only username and password in Java

Tags: java, ldap

I have this .NET project that is able to authenticate an user without any extra info about the LDAP server other than it's address, and I was trying to replicate this behaviour in a Java application

```cs
// C# code that does what I'm trying to do
var entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://ldap.mydomain.com", "username", "p4ssw0rd");
var nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
```

I have tried both the `InitialDirContext` approach and using the `com.unboundid.ldap.sdk` package

```java
var env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, serverAddress);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
var ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
```

But I was only able to get it to work by either using `MYDOMAIN\username` or `cn=username,cn=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com` as the username, not just `username`

Is there some way to replicate the .NET behaviour in Java or is it using some Windows API under the hood to allow that? If that's the case, is there someway to query the LDAP server to find that `MYDOMAIN` value in order to concatenate with the username afterwards? I'm not sure what the name of it would be, `WORKGROUP`, `DN`?

With a search like this

```java
String baseDN = "";
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(
        baseDN,
        SearchScope.BASE,
        Filter.create("(objectClass=*)")
);
```

I was able to get `DC=mydomain,DC=com` from the `rootdomainnamingcontext` attribute, but not `MYDOMAIN`, and I'm a bit afraid to just split that string, grab the first and uppercase it because I'm not sure if that will always be the case.

Comment: Pardon me but I am unfamiliar with [Java] classes `DirectoryEntry` and `SearchRequest`. They do not appear to part of the JDK. Are they classes that you wrote?

Comment: those classes are from the UnboundID LDAP SDK package, from what I've searched, it appears to be the most relevant package for that, but I've also tested with InitialDirContext and had the same results

Comment: about the `DirectoryEntry`, that's a C# snippet that does what I'm trying to replicate, I'll edit the post to make that clearer @Abra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was able to get DC=mydomain,DC=com from the rootdomainnamingcontext attribute, but not MYDOMAIN, and I'm a bit afraid to just split that string, grab the first and uppercase it because I'm not sure if that will always be the case.

No, it won't always be the case (even if you can assume that the LDAP server is indeed AD and not just any generic LDAP). For example, our domain at work is `ad.long-example.com` in DNS but has the NT4 name `EXAMPLE` (because calling it `AD` would've been weird).

However, AD DCs also accept two other formats: in addition to the "NT4 name" you're using, you can also specify a User Principal Name, and you can specify a Kerberos principal name. While the former are customizable per-user, the Kerberos principals are (in AD) always in the fixed format "username@REALM" – unlike UPN suffixes, each domain has exactly one Kerberos realm, which always corresponds to its DNS domain name.

So you can get the Kerberos realm in several ways:

- Uppercase the AD domain name: `mydomain.com` becomes `MYDOMAIN.COM`. (You can look at the 'dnsHostName' LDAP attribute to make sure you have the correct one.)
- Transform the LDAP namingContext back into a domain: `dc=mydomain,dc=com` (with each 'dc=' RDN being a "domain component") becomes `mydomain.com` – uppercase it to get the Kerberos realm.
- Grab it from the `ldapServiceName` attribute: the part after the `@` is the Kerberos realm.

Having that, you can specify `username + "@" + realm` (which is the Kerberos principal name), e.g. `user@MYDOMAIN.COM`, directly as the LDAP bindDN.

Note: Just like the original `MYDOMAIN\user`, **everything mentioned above is AD-specific** and will not work with any non-AD LDAP server. Standard LDAP servers *require* an actual DN as the bindDN, and you will need to do an LDAP search to find it (and you'll need credentials for that, and you'll need to know which OUs contain "users", and you'll also need to know which objectClass defines a "user", and which attribute is used to name the user).

Answer (score 1):

You need the user's DN in order to be able to bind to the LDAP server. In case of AD, you can bind with the SAM Account Name or UPN as well.
I suspect that .Net has some other way of discovering the user's DN value.

> But I was only able to get it to work by either using MYDOMAIN\username or cn=username,cn=Users,dc=mydomain,dc=com as the username, not just username

If you are certain that the supplied username value is the CN, you can search the server with that in order to resolve the DN. Like this:

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(
        baseDN,
        SearchScope.SUB,
        Filter.create("(cn="+username+")")
);
```

**NOTE** In AD the username generally is unique. However in LDAP fashion, the CN may not be guarantueed to be unique. So always check the number of search results before you continue with the bind.